# Is there a way that components from sonar to includes file from subfolders?

Tags: sonarqube

I am using sonar to analyze a c++ project.
When I want to browse the analyses for a particular folder in my project I've seen that only the files in the folder are shown and not files from a sub-folder of the folder.
Those files are shown separately in another "component" that is that particular sub-folder.
Is there a way to define that when analyzing a folder files from sub-folders to be included in it?
Also is there a way to define a level for the components so from that level sub folders to not appear as a component?

For example having:
C:\Trunk\Folder1\subfolder1\more1
C:\Trunk\Folder1\subfolder2\more2

After the analysis the components to be only:
C:\Trunk\Folder1\ and C:\Trunk\Folder2 and Folder1 and Folder2 containing all the file from them and their sub-folders

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're right @Catalin, this is a known Sonar limitation : there is no hierarchical representation of the directory tree.

Comment: I assume this **is still** a limitation, right? Being able to get metrics for a given (hierarchical) level would be awesome. Oh well, we can solve that using `lname` to aggregate the data in the mean time.